# How to perform this text transformation with regex in PyCharm?

Tags: python, regex, intellij-idea, pycharm

I need to perform a somewhat complex text substitution of Python code, within the [IntelliJ PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) editor. The problem lies in that I have to transform a **variable** number of elements into a corresponding set of elements, and I just don't know how to do this with regex (is it even possible?).

I need to transform for example the following text:

```
Contingency([line1], [Case(case1, 1.1), Case(case2, 2)])
```

To this (for example):

```
Contingency([line1], [Case(case1), Case(case2)]).set_max_overload(case1, 1.1).set_max_overload(case2, 2)
```

Note that the `Case` calls (e.g. `Case(case1, 1.1)`) have to be transformed to only retain the first argument (e.g. `Case(case1)`), and that each such call should lead to a corresponding `set_max_overload` call, e.g. `set_max_overload(case1, 1.1)`.

How can I perform the desired text transformation with a regular expression (preferably supported by PyCharm)?

Answer (score 0):

Regex can be written like this:

```
Contingency\(\[(\w+)\], \[(?:Case\((\w+), ([\d\.]+)\))?, (?:Case\((\w+), ([\d\.]+)\))\]\)
```

But replacement is complicated... Replacement's can't vary...

```
Contingency([$1], [Case($2), Case($4)]).set_max_overload($2, $3).set_max_overload($4, $5)
```

As you see... It's overcompicated.. Writing simple parser... Can be simpler.

Comment: So you're saying that this problem is basically unsolvable by regex? If so, that'd be OK by me, if it can't be done it can't be done.

Comment: I mean, if the replacement can not be done by regex, just make that your answer please.

Comment: @aknuds1, Yes and no. You can replace it using regex, but with different regex and replacement strings for each different count of args. Universal regex and replacement can't be composed.

Comment: Well, that's basically the same. I was after a universal regex.

Comment: You might as well state in your answer that this problem is unsolvable by regex, since you can't have a variable number of replacements.